# Чтение запароленного excel файла из под nodejs

Tags: node.js

Стоит задача, парсить запароленный excel-файл.
Есть ли библиотека для чтения запароленного файла?
Познакомился с ExcelJS и Node-xlsx, но про запароленные файлы ничего не написано...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали либу на работе, секция Encryption:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate